# laravel ajax request not print when i add html code in controller

Tags: laravel

In my controller when I remove the html from the code and take message then it works fine but when I used it will give error

POST http://localhost/buyWatch/public/addwatch 500 (Internal Server Error)
/*******************************************************

Ajax code here:

```
<script>

    insertdata();

    function insertdata(){

    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#form_output').hide();

                $("#watch-form").submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

               var formData = new FormData(this);


                    $.ajax( {

                     url:"{{ route('add_watch.postdata') }}",
                     method: "POST",
                     data:formData,
                     dataType: 'json',
                     contentType: false,
                      processData: false,

                      success: function(data) { 

             if(data.error.length > 0)
            {
              $('#form_output').show();
              var data=data.error ;

              var errors = data.responseJSON;

              //var error_html = '';

              $('.alert ul').html(errors);


             /* for(var count = 0; count < data.error.length; count++)
            {

         error_html += data.error[count];
         $('.alert').html(error_html);


          }//for loop end*/

           // $('#form_ul').html(error_html);

            }//if condition 
            else{

                console.log(data.success);
                $('.alert').html("sucess fully updated");

                $("#watch-form")[0].reset();


            }//else end here                               

                        }
                    });
                });

            });//end document


    }//insertData end function


    </script>
```

Controller here:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'watch_name' => 'required',
        'watch_price'  => 'required',
        'watch_quantity'  => 'required',
        'image1'  => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'image2'  =>  'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'image3'  =>  'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'watch_size'  => 'required',
        'discription'  => 'required',

    ]);

    if($request->ajax())
    {



   /// $error_array = array();
    $success_output = array();
    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        foreach($validation->messages()->getMessages() as $field_name => $messages)
        {
           // $error_array[] = $messages;
            $error_array = '<li>'.$messages.'</li>';
        }
    }else{

   $success_output = '<div class="alert alert-success">Data Inserted</div>';

    }

    $output = array(
        'error'     =>  $error_array,
        'success'   =>  $success_output            
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
}
}
```

Comment: why `processData: false,` ??

Answer (score 0):

Can u give us the response of XPOST http://foobar/addWatch ?